# Is it possible to use git svn commands with libgit2sharp?

Tags: libgit2sharp

I am working on an idea which would require parsing through an SVN commit log, something that I know git svn is capable of doing, but I would like to do it via code. Is libgit2sharp able to support this, or does it only handle "real" git?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [...] something that I know git svn is capable of doing [...] Is libgit2sharp able to support this?

`git svn` features are not exposed by **[libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2)**, the core library LibGit2Sharp relies on.

Although this might be implemented one day, it's not on the near future roadmap.

> I am working on an idea which would require parsing through an SVN commit log

I'm not an expert in that field, but this looks like a **[common problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=svn+log+parsing)**. Maybe re-implementing this parsing logic in C# wouldn't take that long.